# How to filter pods in kubernetes dashboard using labels?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

How to select pods from the kubernetes dashboard using labels?

Something similar like this:

```
$ Kubectl get pods -l environment=production,tier=frontend
```

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible so far (v.1.8.1) on the dashboard to filter by label.

Answer (score 0):

This feature hasn't been added so far. I've tried it with version 2.6.1.
Issue on github: [Allow the user to search for labels #3160](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/3160)